# How to change input value in doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

How can I change the attributes of a input form?

I create with this a input (productform.php):

```
$this->add(array(
                'name' => 'categoryId',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'id' => 'categoryId',
                        'type' => 'hidden',
                        'value' => '',
                ),
        ));
```

In a previous page I link to the form and set the special value in the url (`....com/form/3`).

In the indexcontroller.php I get the form with `$form = new ProductForm();` and want edit the value and set the special value from the url.

My idea was the `$form->setAttribute('categoryId', 'value');` but that not working.

Thanks.

indexcontroller.php

```
...
        $form = new ProductForm();
        $form->setHydrator(new CategoryHydrator());
        $form->bind(new Product());
        $form->setAttribute('categoryId', 'value');
....
```

productform.php

```
...

class ProductForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('productForm');
        $this->setAttribute('action', 'newproduct');
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

        $this->add(array(

........
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$form->get('categoryId')->setValue("value");
```

**Update**

So if you just want to fill input, you mean `placeholder` attribute in html. You can use `setAttribute` method.

```
$form->get('categoryId')->setAttribute('placeholder', 'text to show');
```

Answer (score 0):

The form view helper will not allow arbitrary HTML attributes to be set on the form. This is because it would result in invalid HTML.

If you take a look at `Zend\Form\Helper\AbstractHelper` there are two properties `$validGlobalAttributes` and `$validTagAttributes` which define the allowed tags.

In the case of the form view helper (`Zend\Form\View\Helper\Form)` The 'valid tag attributes' will be the `method`, `action` etc

As you require something custom (for JS possibly?); I would change it to a `data-` attribute.

```
 $form->setAttribute('data-categoryId', 'value');
```

The `data-` is [a valid HTML5 attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) which is useful for adding 'domain data' to HTML elements and is really the 'correct' way to do what you require.

Comment: I only want fill the "value" in input.

Comment: I think I've miss understood your issue; @Bilal's answer Is what you need; Although you might want to elaborate on 'not working' and tell us *exactly* what 'didn't work'. Perhaps update your question with the complete controller and form code.